# Getting errors while trying to log inputs from a form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

```js
const socket = io('https://localhost:3000')
const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')

socket.on('chat-message', data =>{
console.log(data)

}
)

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault()
const message = messageInput.value
socket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
messageInput.value = ''
})
```

```
    <script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script defer src="chatscript.js"></script>

<div id="message-container"></div>
    <form id='send-container'>
        <input type="text" id="message-input"></input>
        <button type="submit" id="send-button">send</button>
    </form>
```

When a user enters a submits a message in the input tag, the message should be logged into the console. But instead, i'm getting

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js”.
 file:///C:/Users/myname/Desktop/AvackGames/AvackGames/chatscript.js:1
```

Errors on Firefox and errors on Chrome.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED avackchat.html:9
chatscript.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at chatscript.js:1:16
```

I've tried running "npm install cors" but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: `const socket = io('https://localhost:3000')` change this line to `const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')`

Comment: whats io ?  is it an external library?  If so, did it load?